# How to update Sql table from excel directly?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have an sql database and I am able to connect with excel spreadsheet. But when I update the table from excel directly it's not updating the database and once I click refresh all the entered data is no longer in the excel table

Is it possible to update sql database from excel without using any queries?

Comment: You can use SSIS, or using External tables.

Comment: "when I update the table from excel directly". How are you doing this?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid   , from the spreadsheet like any normal excel file

Comment: How does a piece of data get from the excel file into the database? Do you press a button? It's not normal for data on an excel file to end up in a database. You need to write some code of use some process to do that.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid . Clicking the save button

Comment: When you press the Save button in an excel sheet, you save the excel sheet as a file somewhere. Unless you're pressing a different kind of button that is especially built.

Comment: The short answer is No. The longer answer is Yes but it involves multiple things such as correct permission and code.

Comment: @BIDude  .How its possible

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: Only its not updating to the database

Comment: @Bodhi - you would need to embed connection to server, vba and sql scripts within Excel but the steps are beyond the scope of this comment.

Comment: Where do you define which database it is updating to? Maybe I misunderstand you. I think perhaps you have an excel sheet that you want to write back to a DB but.... you have absolutely nothing that actually does that

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can directly via VBA or with other tools.

1. via VBA (via qry)
2. via SSIS (https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/moving-data-from-excel-to-sql-server-10-steps-to-follow/)
3. via managament studio (https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/203/simple-way-to-import-data-into-sql-server/)
4. via MS ACCESS (with ODBC connection to server)
   ...