# How to update MSSQL from Excel using excel VBA

Tags: sql-server, excel

**Current Situation**

I have a database in MSSQL and currently it is able to link to excel the following way.

[image]

Excel table which is connected to MSSQL as follows

[image]

MSSQL table as below

[image]

Currently if I update my MSSQL table, excel table will update accordingly

**What I need**

I want the vice versa operation. Means whenever I update the excel table, MSSQL also needs to update. Is this possible?

Comment: You can truncate & load the MSSQL table with the excel file after any update. You can use SSIS to achieve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update Sql table from excel directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42732802/how-to-update-sql-table-from-excel-directly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to do it correctly by using following code

```html
Sub updateSqlFromExcel()
Dim cnn As ADODB.connection
Dim uSQL As String
Set cnn = New connection
    cnnstr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; " & _
            "Data Source=myServer; " & _
            "Initial Catalog=myDatabaseName;" & _
            "User ID=username;" & _
            "Password=password;" & _
            "Trusted_Connection=No"
            Set rngName = ActiveCell
    cnn.Open cnnstr
    
    excelId = ActiveCell.Value 'This is just an example
    excelSeq = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value 'This is just an example
    excelName = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value 'This is just an example
    
    uSQL = "UPDATE myTableName SET Name = '" & excelName & "', Seq = '" & excelSeq & "' WHERE ID= '" & excelId & "' "
    cnn.Execute uSQL
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    MsgBox "Updated successfully. But please wait until background refresh finish before close excel", vbInformation, "Success"
    cnn.Close
    Set cnn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Please change `myServer`, `myDatabaseName`, `username`, `password`and `myTableName`according to your settings in order for this macro to work. Also please add reference library `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library`. In order to add, press Alt+F11 and then goto Tools --> References. Scroll to `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library` and tick the checkbox. Press ok and you are ready to go.