# How to update SQL Server table from Excel data

Tags: sql-server, excel

I've a vendor table in SQL Server with vendor code, vendor ID and vendor name. Another table called disc_mast with columns vendor ID and disc_per. Vendors will revise disc% frequently and we will get the details in Excel with vendor code and disc%. How can I update the discount percent in the disc_mast from the data in excel without importing the data in Excel to SQL Server tables.

Comment: When you say "Excel" do you mean actual `*.xlsx` files, or just `*.csv` files? (and if CSV, which dialect/format? MySQL's CSV is very different to Excel's CSV, for example)

Comment: Does this help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42732802/how-to-update-sql-table-from-excel-directly/42739814

Comment: the file can be in any format as it is sent by third party.

Comment: @KeyvanSoleimani This seems to be too complicated

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you do not want to import the data to SQL Server tables? It seems it would make more sense import the data anyway, and record the import date/time, so that you have a record of the changes rather than just overwriting the previous discount? If you really wanted to avoid importing the data you can use SSIS to read the file, then perform an SQL Command on each row to update the database, but honestly you'd be better off just importing the data to a staging table and updating using that, so keen to understand why you can't/don't want to import the data?

Comment: _the file can be in any format as it is sent by third party._ Then you're going to have to figure out how to handle it each time they send you a new file. It's important to nail down data suppliers to a particular format so you can use automated ETL processes instead of mandraulics.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning. Thank you for your suggestion. will try to keep a single format all the time.

Comment: *"the file can be in any format as it is sent by third party."* but you say in your question *"we will get the details in Excel with vendor code and disc%"* so how does the file vary?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
Sub Update()

'Declare some variables
Dim cnn As adodb.Connection
Dim cmd As adodb.Command
Dim strSQL As String

'Create a new Connection object
Set cnn = New adodb.Connection

'Set the connection string
cnn.ConnectionString = "Your_Server_Name;Database=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=True;"

'Create a new Command object
Set cmd = New adodb.Command

'Open the connection
cnn.Open
'Associate the command with the connection
cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn

'Tell the Command we are giving it a bit of SQL to run, not a stored procedure
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

'Create the SQL
strSQL = "UPDATE TBL SET JOIN_DT = 2013-01-13 WHERE EMPID = 2"

'Pass the SQL to the Command object
cmd.CommandText = strSQL

'Open the Connection to the database
cnn.Open

'Execute the bit of SQL to update the database
cmd.Execute

'Close the connection again
cnn.Close

'Remove the objects
Set cmd = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing

End Sub
```

This is VBA code that runs in Excel. Also, create a reference to 'Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects x.x Library'.

Tools -. References:

[image]